# How to use ORACLE sequence for spring boot jpa non-id proprety

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Is it possible to use a DB sequence (oracle 19c)  for some column that is not the identifier/is not part of a composite identifier?

I'm using hibernate as jpa provider,spring boot and I have a table that has some columns that are generated values (using a sequence), although they are not part of the identifier.

What I want is to use a sequence to create a new value for an entity, where the column for the sequence is NOT (part of) the primary key: